# use of to_datetime commands on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time-series, arima

What is the difference between the following two commands?

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I read somewhere that the second command is for strings in the data

Comment: the first line : pandas is iterating each line and execute a function 'outside' of pandas with the apply method. The second line, everything is inside pandas

Comment: from an end-user perspective, you'll find the second operation is much faster on large data frames